# Pervasive SQL v.11 ODBC Client Interface

Tags: driver, psql, pervasive

I have Pervasive PSQL v.11 server but no PervasiveClient Interface driver on it. I looked for answer and what i found is to install Pervasive Client on server but i am afraid that it may mess the server or configuration. So I am looking for any way to install that driver without installing client application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install the Pervasive Server, it installs the client as well.  You should have the Pervasive Client Interface.  Make sure you are using the 32 bit ODBC Administrator.  It is located in the %systemdrive%\windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe.  The ODBCAD32.EXE in %systemdrive%\Windows\System32 is 64 bit.  I know it seems backward but that's how Microsoft did it.
If you are seeing just the "Pervasive ODBC Interface", you are using the 64 bit ODBC Administrator.
Another option would be to use the Pervasive Control Center.  It can create the 32 bit DSN when creating the database.  It also has menu options (under Tools) for the 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC Administrator.